# bootstrap button spacing lost after render jade template with express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

Hi I am using angular with express and using jade as templating engine.
When i render a partial that is a jade template rendered view looks different than
when i render a partial without using jade.

The example is ; when using jade space between buttons is lost like the attached image.

Here us what i am trying;

**index.jade**

```
body
    block content
        div(class="container-fluid")
            div(class="row")
                div(class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2")
                    include ../public/app/views/sidebar/main.sidebar.jade

                div(class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10")
                    div(ng-view class="row") ----> i am trying to render view here
```

**editor.html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">   
  <div class="container" style="width:inherit;">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>Execute    
        </button>  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk text-primary"></span>Save    
        </button>  
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body"> <div id="editor"></div> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="width:inherit;" ng-include src="'/app/partials/editor/result.grid.html'"></div>
</div>
```

when rendered with html
see not only spaces between buttons but also spaces inside buttons icon and text 
[image: buttons with html rendering]

**editor.jade**

```
div(class="col-md-12" ng-controller="EditorCtrl")   
  div(class="container" style="width:inherit;")
    div.panel
      div(class="panel-heading clearfix")
        button(type="button" class="btn btn-success")
          span(class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash") Execute    
        button(type="button" class="btn btn-default")
          span(class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk text-primary") 
      div.panel-body
        div(id="editor")
  div(class="container" style="width:inherit;")
```

and in express app.js

```
app.get('/app/views/editor/editor.jade', function(req, res){
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('../public/app/views/editor/editor.jade');
});
```

i also observe the problem in other components rendered as a partial in jade

html
[image: html]

jade
[image: jade]

[image: buttons without spacing]

Comment: Have you compared the rendered HTML for the buttons in both cases? That might be helpful to see.

Comment: yes i did and they look same (to me). Actually i think the problem is with applying style during render but then i think again and ask ; if there is a problem during rendering then how buttons are rendered anyway. btw i put rendered html and jade versions to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jade template is correct, and your problem have nothing to do with Boostrap, to have space beetween buttons you have just to add `nbsp's`

```
.col-md-12(ng-controller='EditorCtrl')
  .container(style='width:inherit;')
    .panel
      .panel-heading.clearfix
        button.btn.btn-success(type='button')
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-flash Execute


        | &nbsp;

        button.btn.btn-default(type='button')
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-floppy-disk.text-primary


      .panel-body
        #editor
  .container(style='width:inherit;')
```

[image]

The HTML rendered by your jade is the following:

```
<div ng-controller="EditorCtrl" class="col-md-12"><div style="width:inherit;" class="container"><div class="panel"><div class="panel-heading clearfix"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash">Execute</span></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk text-primary">Save</span></button></div><div class="panel-body"><div id="editor"></div></div></div></div><div style="width:inherit;" class="container"></div></div>
```

You will not find any white space beetween elements, so if you don't want use nbsp's in your jade, you should insert whitespace, as you already do in your HTML, otherwise jade does not know the need to do

```
.col-md-12(ng-controller='EditorCtrl')
  .container(style='width:inherit;')
    .panel
      .panel-heading.clearfix
        button.btn.btn-success(type='button')
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-flash Execute
        | 
        button.btn.btn-default(type='button')
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-floppy-disk.text-primary Save


      .panel-body
        #editor
  .container(style='width:inherit;')
```

[image]

You could be interested in this [**discussion**](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/905)

Try yourself, if you put space(or carriage-return) beetween flow elements(as buttons) you will see the same behaviour

```html
<button>Test</button><button>Test</button><br/>
<button>Test</button>
<button>Test</button><br/>
```

Comment: when i place | &nbsp;&nbsp; i got the space but i think if there is one  to one conversion between jade and html then i should not need the space characters am i right?

Comment: yes it works with extra space chars. but in html it works without these explicit spaces why there is a difference? And if i start adding those spaces around each time i add a component there will be spaces which will look strange

Comment: sorry i just realized 'not jade' and i updated the post

Comment: i have also added the html output actually all spacesing seems to be gone when using jade. i mean also the spaces between button icon and button text.

Comment: am i missing something _"You will not find any white space beetween elements, so if you don't want use nbsp's in your jade, you should insert whitespace, **as you already do in your HTML**, otherwise jade does not know the need to do"_ where do i put spaces. and what about the spaces between button img and button text do i have to put spaces there too. btw. sorry my questions seems a bit dumb this is first time i am writing an html code i could be missing some points in your comments.

Comment: you put carriage return beetween flow elements(your buttons), please have a look to my last snippet

Comment: finally got it with your last edit. I didn't know that CR interpreted as space. Thanks a lot.